# Is it possible to have things orbit around us?

Tags: newtonian-gravity

Since humans are not large in mass, do we exert enough gravitational force for a small object to orbit around us? (Assuming that the only gravitational force acting on the object is from the human). Using Newton's law of gravity and using myself as the human mass, I exert a 10^-8 force on a 1 kg object .5 meter away, but I am not sure if even this small of a force will be acceptable. What is the baseline "force" between two objects for 1 to orbit another?

Edit: I am not sure if this is a SpaceExchange question.

Comment: What do you mean "How accurately can you measure?" Do you mean how I got those numbers? Or that it is hard to answer this question?

Comment: No, sorry for the misunderstanding, what I meant was, the gravitational force caused by your mass is so small that, in theory, things **can** orbit around us/you, and for all I know they do, but trying to measure a baseline force   would be difficult.  _I am not sure if this is a SpaceExchange question._  it's actually Physics.StackExchange

Comment: Ah I see, so I'm guessing that in theory things can orbit us, but there is no way to tell.

Comment: Don't accept it yet, you will get a better answer later, no rush, it is only a short reply. Get the best idea you can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Our mass is so small that large, I mean large enough to be visible things, like a fly, could (and do) easily escape our bodies tiny gravitational pull, but smaller things, like an atom, may for a short while be stuck in orbit around us, but we can't detect them very easily, if at all. Gravity is a very,very,very weak force.

A related answer [Humans And Gravity](http://www.askamathematician.com/2010/04/q-how-big-does-an-object-have-to-be-to-gravitationally-attract-a-human-or-have-a-molten-core/) to illustrate how weak gravity is:

> What is the critical point for gravity to attract a human? In other words, if you were to make a big pile of rocks in space, at what mass would they drag a human towards them?
>   Even Deimos (the smaller of Mars’ two moons) has an escape velocity of only about 12.5 mph, so with a good running start you could literally jump into space.  I figure 12.5 mph is about the fastest that most people can muster in a pinch, so Deimos is about the smallest object that can hold people down, at about 8 miles across (8 miles on average, due to lumpiness).

Diemos  has a mass of 1.4762 X 10$^{15} $ kg ,  compared to say 80 to 100+ kg for a human.

Answer (score 2):

If there are no other forces to disturb them, then even arbitrarily small objects can orbit each other.  Because the forces in your example are very small, the orbit speed would be very small.  But that's okay.

The problem comes when other forces are near.  They can overwhelm the smaller orbital forces.  When the forces that interfere are other gravitational forces, then we can use the concept of the [Hill sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_sphere), the region where your gravity dominates over your neighbor's.  It depends on your mass and the mass and distance of nearby objects.

So you can have two astronauts orbit each other out in intergalactic space.  But in earth orbit, that would not be possible.  The gravity of the earth perturbs things too much.

Comment: I figured this much since I don't believe there is a point in space where it is not influenced by some sort of force

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the queerest thing but I'm not sure it's right. I know that it takes 90 minutes for a low-orbit sattelite to circle the earth. So I scaled the earth down by a factor of 2. This gives me half the gravity, so I equated v-squared-over-r to half. I got the the velocity is exactly half to balance out.

This is very queer. It means a low-orbit satellite would cirlce my "half-earth" in exactly...ninety minutes.

So scale it down to a sphercial mass the size of a human being (but give it a density of 5.5, which is the average density of earth) and the orbital period for a "low-orbit" satellite would be...90 minutes. I can hardly believe this is right.

So neglecting the difference in density and the deviation from spherical geometery, if you were an astronaut in outer space, far from any other bodies, you could have a fly orbiting your body once every ninety minutes. Or a brick, for that matter...the satellite doesn't have to be small compared to you.

Someone tell me I'm wrong.

Comment: In this answer http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/130754/put-a-bullet-into-orbit-around-the-moon/130766#130766, I showed that:  the orbital period of a surface grazing satellite depends on only the density of the primary...

Comment: Yes, you did it very cleanly. I'm surprised that time and density are related by a universal constant.

Comment: ... that constant being none other than the universal constant of gravity. Its dimension is acceleration [of a test particle] per mass [of the central body] per inverse distance squared, i.e. $\rm\frac{m/s^2}{kg\cdot m^{-2}}$, which is the same as $\rm\frac{s^{-2}}{kg/m^3}$, or frequency squared per density.

Comment: Yes, I see. It is the same constant, give or take a factor of 2*pi or so.