# How to solve this long distance projectile problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gravity, kinematics, projectile, centripetal-force

A projectile is fired horizontally from the top of a mountain of height 'h' at a very high velocity. The projectile **almost** completes one revolution around the earth and crash lands at the bottom of the mountain (coming from the opposite side after circling the earth). I know that if it was fired at the orbital velocity, it would have orbited the earth in uniform circular motion. Hence, I assume the initial velocity in the question would be lower than the orbital velocity. The path taken by the projectile in this scenario seems to be a spiral. And there would be tangential acceleration as well, apart from centripetal acceleration, I believe.

**At what velocity should we fire the the projectile for taking such a path?** What would be the final velocity? (Assume the earth to be a perfect sphere and neglect atmospheric drag)

My approach was to find the work done by centripetal force at an instant (F.dh), then integrate it and equate it to mgh. (For uniform circular motion, work done by the centripetal force would be zero). But, it's a bit complicated method since both 'v' and and 'r' in mv^2/r are variables, and has to be expressed in polar co-ordinates.

[image]

Comment: Great problem in that exploring the limits of projectile motion by removing the constant (direction) of gravity assumption. But, what have you tried in terms of solving this? Is there any work/equations you can post also.

Comment: The described event does not occur in the absence of air friction...

Comment: Related question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/130754/268448

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The path described is impossible. Without air drag, the projectile should move along an ellipse. So if you trace it around it should end up where it started due to conservation of energy.

Here is a picture of the limiting case for going around I think.

[image: fig]

You might be tempted to make the following case, but this is also physically impossible.

[image: fig2]

Although the projectile is following an ellipse, another rule of orbital motion is that the center of mass (center of earth in this case) has to be on one of the ellipse foci. The foci is offset from the center of the ellipse, and in the diagram above the ellipse is concentric to the earth.

**So the rule is, if it misses the earth on the other side exactly, it will continue and return back to the launch point.**

I suggest the *op* lookup some references to orbital mechanics, and see if they can work out the problem on their own, as it presents some great learning experiences.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. In that case, at what velocity should we fire the projectile so as to make it land exactly on the opposite side?

Comment: @Curiouserandcuriouser - here are some [online references](http://www.braeunig.us/space/orbmech.htm) for [you to explore](https://web.aeromech.usyd.edu.au/AERO4701/Course_Documents/AERO4701_week2.pdf) and see if you can work out the answer yourself. Remember that [Physics.SE] discourages (if not prohibits) the posting of complete solutions for homework style problems (even if they are not actual homework).

Comment: Wow this is a detailde answer

Answer (score 1):

Lossless (iso-energetic) orbits:

The sum of energy kinectic + potential remain constant - no airdrag or such: these orbits are elliptical. If shot horizontally, there is one distinct speed, for which the orbit is circular. Slower speeds will mean that the starting point is the apogee, and the projectile will first drop altitude & gain velocity until perigee, and then slow down again and gain potential energy, until it's at the starting point (unless impact on earth / other stuff earlier). Higher speeds mean that the starting point is the perigee. That is until escape velocity.
These orbits are also called Kepler orbits, and there are Kepler's laws governing it. For your case - you could calculate total energy states (potential+kinetic).
For Kepler orbits you wouldn't need integration (see also [conservative vector field][1])

lossy orbits (with energy dissipation):

The spiral you depicted would not be an iso-energetic orbit - your projectile would need to lose energy, so e.g. airdrag helps. How much? Here is where the fun starts: airdrag is not a linear function of velocity, so I'd point you to numerical integration.

Comment: If I'm correct, orbits happen (elliptical or circular) only at velocities more than or equal to the orbital velocity and less than the escape velocity. I was wondering what would happen if we fire at a velocity only slightly lower than the orbital velocity. I thought the path would be a spiral, but I think if the velocity is lower than orbital velocity, the maximum the projectile would travel is till the opposite end of earth. As it is mentioned in the previous answer, "So the rule is, if it misses the earth on the other side exactly, it will continue and return back to the launch point."

Comment: Yes that's the essence of the elliptical (Kepler-) orbit. The satellite / projectile will stay on that same ellipse trajectory, unless other than the central gravitational forces act on it. 

That said, this ellipse will not rotate with earth. So if your tower is built somewhere else that at a one of the poles, the tower on earths surface will move away while the projectile is flying.